# Use files in the public folder within template subfolder in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony5

I'm currently using CSS in my Twig templates. The CSS is in my public folder and templates are in the templates folder.
So the following code is working actually :`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/css/style.css">`

Here comes the problem. I created a sub directory in the templates folder but when I try to access to the CSS like before; Symfony don't find my CSS file.
I fixed this issue by using `../` before the href so I have this :`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/libs/css/style.css">`

My problem is solved at this point but I want something more generic than `../` because if I have some folders inside a folder which is inside the templates folder I would have something like that `../../../` and it's really ugly.

So I am currently looking for a generic way to access to the public folder no matter where I am in the templates folder.
If my question isn't clear enough I know how to do this in Blade with `{{ URL::to('/') }}` so in Blade my code would have been like that : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/assets/libs/css/style.css">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony has a twig function for what you want as part of the [Asset-component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html). If you use Webpack Encore you will likely already have this installed otherwise you can install it via composer:

```sh
composer require asset
```

This should create a default configuration for you and you should be able to use the following in your templates:

```
{{ asset('/assets/libs/css/style.css') }}
```

As the docs for [Linking to CSS, JavaScript and Image Assets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#templates-link-to-assets) state:

> The `asset()` function's main purpose is to make your application more portable. If your application lives at the root of your host (e.g. `https://example.com`), then the rendered path should be `/images/logo.png`. But if your application lives in a subdirectory (e.g. `https://example.com/my_app`), each asset path should render with the subdirectory (e.g. `/my_app/images/logo.png`). The `asset()` function takes care of this by determining how your application is being used and generating the correct paths accordingly.